# expected unqualified id before '{' token

Tags: c++

I have searched all over the place and cannot find an answer to this rather frequently recoccuring error. Its really starting to annoy me.

Anyhow, this is the error i am getting:

```
74:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
81:21: error: ‘chat’ has not been declared
81:5: warning: second argument of ‘int main(int, int**)’ should be ‘char **’ [-Wmain]
118:10: error: ‘clean_up’ was not declared in this scope
```

I might as well just post the whole program as to avoid confusion. Might I note I am following a tutorial and yet still getting these errors. The tutorial offers no help!

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include <string>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
const int SCREEN_BBP = 32;

SDL_Surface* image = NULL;
SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;

SDL_Event event;

SDL_Surface *load_image( std::string filename )
{

SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;

SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;

loadedImage = IMG_Load( filename.c_str() );

if( loadedImage != NULL )
    {

    optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat( loadedImage );

    SDL_FreeSurface( loadedImage );
    }

return optimizedImage;
}
void apply_surface( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination )
{
    SDL_Rect offset;

    offset.x = x;
    offset.y - y;

    SDL_BlitSurface( source, NULL, destination, &offset );
}
bool init()
{

    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) == -1 )
    {
        return false;
    }

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BBP, SDL_SWSURFACE ); 

    if( screen == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }

    SDL_WM_SetCaption( "Event test" , NULL );

    return true;
}

bool load_files()
{

    image = load_image( "x.png" );

    if(image == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
{

SDL_FreeSurface( image );

SDL_Quit();
}

int main( int argc, chat* args[] )
{

    bool quit = false;


    if( init() == false )
    {
    return 1;
    }

    if( load_files() == false )
    {
        return 1;
    }

apply_surface( 0, 0, image, screen );

if(SDL_Flip( screen ) == -1 )
{
    return 1;
}

while( quit == false )
    {

        while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
        {

            if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {

                quit = true;
            }
        }
    }

clean_up();

return 0;
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mee it looks like you accidently inserted a semicolon in line 42:

```
bool init();
{ //this is line 43 in which the compiler is pointing at.
```

Try it like this:

```
bool init()
{ //this is line 43 in which the compiler is pointing at.
```

Comment: i tried that and it came up with a bunch of other similar errors

Comment: Could you show us the errors? Perhaps you have simmilar mistakes elsewhere in the code

Answer (score 1):

```
bool init(); // <--- you have an extra semicolon here
{ //this is line 43 in which the compiler is pointing at.
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon `bool init();`